# How to send the form with submit event instead of AJAX post?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, yandex-metrika

I use Yandex.Metrika to track user activities on my site (like Google Analytics does). It has an option to track how user works with html forms - what he/she inputs there, how much time spends on each field etc. ([link in Russian](http://help.yandex.ru/metrika/behavior/web-forms.xml)). But in order to work properly, it requires to submit the form with `submit` event.

I have the following code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="utsDetails">
...
<button type="button" id="calc" name="calc">Calculate</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#calc").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
           // all utsDetails form fields are there
        },          
        beforeSend: function(){
           // ...
        }
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // ...
      });
```

Is there any way to modify my code to keep the functionality unchanged (i.e. page shouldn't be reloaded on button is pressed, result should be received as JSON, `beforeSend` and `done` functions should be executed etc.), but to send the form data with `submit`?

Comment: Did you try to bind to submit event instead of click? Like $("#utsDetails").submit(function() ... instead of $("#calc").click(function() {

Comment: What do you mean? Sending a `POST` is the same as what happens when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes helped me:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="utsDetails" method="POST" action="/"> <!-- added method and action -->
...
<button type="submit" id="calc" name="calc">Calculate</button> <!-- replaced  type with "submit" -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#utsDetails").submit(function() { // instead of $("#calc").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
           // all utsDetails form fields are there
        },          
        beforeSend: function(){
           // ...
        }
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // ...
      });
      return true; // to avoid page reload
```